# Align text in absolute middle with fittext.js in responsive layout

Tags: css, responsive-design, position, alignment, fittextjs

like the title says I am desperately trying to center a text `h1` in the middle of a responsive element. I tried around for 2 hours now and can't seem to get it work correctly. What am I doing wrong?

I tried `absolute` positioning and `-` margins but that seemed not really accurate:

```
.category-description{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: -10% 0 0 -30%;
    font: 16px/1.8 "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
}
```

I made a JSFiddle for better understanding

[Fiddle goes here](http://jsfiddle.net/gm8ceocq/4/)

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if you don't need support for much older browsers:

```
.category-description{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    font: 16px/1.8 "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
}
```